# Javascript - missing ; before statement

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm studying with a tutorial for a "drawing app". When I launch my app on Firefox, Firebug tells me *"missing ; before statement"* where I call my function on line 9. I just don't get where I'm supposed to put these ";".

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var radius = 10;

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

var putPoint = Function(e){
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(e.clientX, e.clientY, radius, 0, Math.PI*2); 
    context.fill();
}

canvas.addEventListener ('mousedown', putPoint);

/* ligne 15 context.arc(x, y, radius, start, end) */
```

Comment: Is this the whole code? `Function` souldn't be `function`? Error messages are not always what they seems to mean.

Comment: JavaScript is case-sensitive. Your function definition needs to say literally `function` (all lowercase) rather than `Function` as you have.

Comment: Thanks a lot to the both of you, i'm verry new at javascript and it's still kinda hard for me, now it work just as I wanted to. thx again.

Comment: You should also have a semi-colon after the function definition.

Answer (score 2):

1. `var putPoint = Function(e)` ---> `var putPoint = function(e)`
2. `contint.fill(); }` ---> `contint.fill(); };`